# App is NOT Crashing While Debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

I am facing a strange issue in my currently working app. App is crashing when we install app through diawi or directly install using .ipa . But I am not able to regenerate the issue through debugging. I am totally confused and how can I solve the issue?

I am using Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: check once in device console, for e.g install the app via diawi and xcode --> window --> devices and simulators --> check the crash report

Comment: Plug the device in, go to the devices window in Xcode and download the crash log and symbolicate it.

Comment: @Paulw11 from where I can download crash log

Comment: Do you mean that app is not crashing when cable is plugged-in or app is not crashing when you enabled some breakpoint in xcode ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia App is not crashing when we take build through Xcode

Comment: plz check all permission regarding access notification, contact, location etc. if without this authorise if you access then that might be crash also

Comment: @user6788419 From the device in the devices window in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

You can try building the app in Xcode in the Release configuration instead of the Debug configuration.

You do this by

- clicking on your app name at the top left (near where you press to run the app)
- choosing 'Edit Scheme' from the drop down
- clicking on the disclosure indicator by 'Run'
- choosing 'Run' from the three choices which appear
- there is a drop down called 'Build Configuration'. This will almost certainly be set to Debug. Set this to Release.

Now when you run your app you will be building a far more optimised version - this is the version you build when you are submitting to Apple. It's just the same app optimised for speed/memory instead of debugability.

Hopefully, you should be able to reproduce your crash in Xcode now. However, you'll notice that you get far less debugging information when you hit your crash - this is because Debug builds have lots of extra information in (and are much less optimised by the compiler) specifically to make debugging easier. Being able to reproduce the crash in Xcode should give you a few more clues as to what's going on. At the least you should be able to see the chunk of code causing you issues.

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Use crash tracking tool to track crash here is the detail about installing [crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)